# Are these harmful files that were scanned on my Mac safe to delete?

Tags: macos

[image: Threats Found]

The scan says the threat is blocked but for more safety I'm considering removing them. Is it safe to do so since some files seem to be system files.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should remove these files.
VSearch is adware for OS X. You can find more information about VSearch here:

- [Removing VSearch or OSX/Vsearch threat from your Mac — support.norton.com](https://support.norton.com/sp/en/uk/home/current/solutions/v103225891_EndUserProfile_en_us)

Whilst these files are in system locations such as /System, they are not part of OS X. The adware simply places files in those locations to obfuscate the actions of the adware.